# Applet JTextArea copy and paste issue on MAC

Tags: java, macos, applet, jtextarea, osx-mavericks

I am using a simple JtextArea in the Applet so that we can copy and paste the content.

When I run the Applet in Windows it works properly, I can copy and paste the content to and from the applet.

When I run the Applet in MAC 10.9 Mavericks then first time it works fine but when we copy the content from the Jtextarea after that it behaving in differently.

ForExample:

> I copy the content "11111" from the Notepad and paste it on Applet JTextArea .
>   Works  fine
>
> I Copy the content "22222" from JTextArea and paste it on NotePad.
>   Works fine
>
> Now I Copy the content "33333" from NotePad and try to paste on JTextArea
>   Then it will paste the previously copied "2222".
>   and If I paste it on NotePad, it will paste "333333".

So that means to me that Java is caching the clipboard content,  is that correct?
How can I resolve this ?

Comment: OK, but what's the question?

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: See there is one JTextArea from where I am copying the content and paste it on somewhere else like "word ,Note etc" and a vice verse

In Mac What happen is, copied content from JtextArea is not being overrided by other application

Like if I copy some text from the NotePad and trying to paste it on the Applet JTextArea , It paste the previously Copyied text

Why this is happening ??